# 14.04 Installer crashed because of low disk space

Tags: system-installation, disk

my computer has a 500GB hard drive and I did the delete everything choice, but I am getting an error when trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
HELP...it's older hardware...

Comment: your /var partition has less than 0.0MB of free space available, which leads to problems using applications and installing updates. Please free some space.

Comment: I am a complete noob when it comes to Linux, but it shouldn't be this difficult to get a clean install.

Comment: Press "Try Ubuntu" at the beginning. After the live system is completely loaded press STRG+ALT+T and input "sudo fdisk -l" (without the quotes). Than start Firefox in the life system and post the result here please (edit your question to add it).